# Passing an local varaible from one template to another template in xslt

Tags: xslt

I am trying to covert an xml to html using xslt.
Now I got struck with the use of variables in xslt.
Is it possible to  pass variables from parent node to some other template other than child node?
I have amy xslt code like this
`

```
<xsl:template match="xpath"name="a">
<xsl:variable name="object" select="Hello">
<xsl:call-template="b">
<xsl:with-param name="object" select="$object"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xpath" name="b">
<xsl:param name="object"/>
</xsl:template>
```

`

I am getting an following error
`unexpected xslt element 'param'`

Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is `xsl:varaible` a typo or an error in your real code? The same for `template match="xpath"name="b"`, there is a space missing between the `match` attribute value and the next attribute `name`.

Comment: sorry,that is the typing mistake

Comment: Is xsl:varaible a typo or an error in your real code?-->cant get you clearly.

Comment: The word is spelled `variable` and not `varaible` so your code is wrong. Consider to post minimal but complete and tested code samples that allow us to reproduce the exact error you get, things like `<xsl:template match="xpath"name="a">` with another missing space will never get by the XML parser so we don't have to talk about XSLT if you don't even have the XML syntax right.

Comment: There is no syntatical errors in my code.Help me with this issue of passing a variable's value from one template to another

Comment: See the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#call-template-params for instance for a syntactically correct example, your example is not XML as `<xsl:template match="xpath"name="a">` for instance lacks a space before `name="a"`. It is also not clear how you expect to declare a variable named `object` and pass on a parameter of the same name without having an outer value declared that way.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with the code that has been shared.

1. XSL template cannot have both `match` and `name` attributes specified. You can either have a `match` attribute or `name` attribute. The `match` attribute can go with the `mode` attribute if you are looking to match with same element from input XML.
2. XSL variable `object` has been declared and a value of `Hello` assigned to it. However you are also calling a template `b` from inside the `<xsl:variable>` which is not correct. XSL variables cannot have `select` and `content` both.

You may want to modify the code as below if you are looking for passing a parameter from one template to another.

```
<!-- template matching with input XML -->
<xsl:template match="xpath">
    <!-- declare variable "object" and assign value as "Hello" -->
    <xsl:variable name="object" select="'Hello'" />

    <!-- call template "b" and pass the value of variable "object" -->
    <xsl:call-template name="b">
        <xsl:with-param name="object" select="$object" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<!-- create template "b" using @name attribute -->
<xsl:template name="b">
    <!-- declare parameter -->
    <xsl:param name="object" />

    <!-- print the value of parameter -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$object" />
</xsl:template>
```